# Can I create a build rule for monitoring changes in a plist and calling a method at runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiappearance

I am building a theme engine for an iOS app and would love to be able to detect changes to a plist file that would then update the bundle and trigger a method in my code to re-apply the styles I have amended. This is a `UIAppearance` proxy manager.

I'm sure this is possible because CSS/Ios frameworks I have used like NUI and Pixate have the ability to monitor changes in the CSS.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: why did you remove the xcode tag? The answer probably lies somewhere in setting a build rule for monitoring the file system. This is handled in xcode is it not?

Comment: can't you check MD5 hash of the plist periodically and call a method if changed?

Comment: interesting. Will look into it. Can you post some code?